# Reviewing reopen votes for a question which shows no changes

Tags: discussion, review-queues, reopen-closed

While Reviewing reopen votes, what should I do when I am presented with a **closed** question which shows **no changes** whatsoever? Why would I ever choose to reopen it?

**Example:**

[image: Screenshot of a question closed as off-topic]

Comment: It certainly seems like it was wrongly closed. Running an installer and uninstaller seems like it would be a normal part of a testing / ci process to make sure some build installs correctly and uninstalls correctly.

Comment: If this question is off-topic or is not mine to judge. However why would someone want to reopen a question that is more then 8 years old?

Comment: Here is a link to the question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/450027/uninstalling-an-msi-file-from-the-command-line-without-using-msiexec

Comment: @Luuklag Ostensibly to answer it, though it could be OP asking for it to be reopened out of pride or out of concern for the negative impact to their account from the perspective of the system. A closed question counts against some of your badge progress and can harm the user's ability to ask new questions, depending.

Comment: +1 example: https://stackoverflow.com/review/reopen/26576847

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> Why would I ever choose to reopen it?

Well, you might disagree that the question should have been closed in the first place. Closures are sometimes mistakes, like anything else.

I don't have any idea what your example question is talking about, but it might be that it's asking about a programming-specific tool, and is in fact on topic.

Comment: Just FYI, the question is asking about installing programs in general (MSI files are Microsoft installers). That's off-topic, but this question pre-dates that rule. The close reason is also old and doesn't properly reflect this. If this were to be reopened, I would reclose it as belonging on [Super User](//superuser.com). This question might also be a candidate for a historical lock.

Answer (score 11):

Reopen votes also push a question into the queue, as they indicate the closure was disputed and should be reviewed.

From the [help](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/close-questions):

> Similarly, **the reopen queue will contain any post that currently has an active reopen vote**. Users can vote to reopen, edit the question (which includes a reopen vote), or leave the question closed. A certain number of Leave Closed votes will again kick the question out of the queue and begin the reopen vote aging process, and of course, another reopen vote will put it back into the queue. Questions which get edited within 5 days of being closed will automatically show up in the reopen queue for review. Questions which have had a revision will add an extra tab at the top so that you can quickly view the revision. Like the close votes queue, questions which were closed as duplicates will still list the duplicates in the tabs above.

The post in question currently has one reopen vote atm, thus it was in the queue.

Answer (score 2):

Re-open reviews are tricky. I do like this:

- Open up the edit history and check what the question looked like at the point where it was closed.
- Try to determine if the question was correctly closed or not. Sometimes you need domain knowledge for this. If you aren't certain, skip the review - skipping is perfectly fine.
- If you think the question was incorrectly closed, cast a re-open vote. Review done.
- If you think the question was correctly closed, check the edit history to see what changes that were made since the post was closed. Is the reason why the question was closed addressed in the changes?
- If the reason why the question was closed was fixed *and* the question is otherwise fine, vote to re-open. If the question has not been fixed or if there is yet another reason that it should be closed, vote to leave closed.

In this particular case, at a glance it doesn't look like a programming question to me. In which case it is off-topic and definitely should remain closed. However, I personally lack domain knowledge about these things, so I would skip this review.

Answer (score 2):

You've picked quite an edge case here. There's several things in play beyond a normal closure

1. The question is about General Computing. Yes, as a programmer you have to install programs sooner or later, but the question isn't about installing a specific tool, it's about installation of [MSI files](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa266434(v=vs.60).aspx) in general. We have a SE website for this kind of thing now: [Super User](//superuser.com)
2. The question was asked in 2009. It pre-dates Super User. Doesn't mean the rules don't apply, it just means that it was an acceptable question back in the day (note the closure happened 4 years later)
3. The closure reason is old. We now have a specific "general computing" closure reason, instead of the generic "Off-topic" that was used. If you hang around Reopen long enough, you'll see these float by from time to time (another oldie was `Not constructive`). This underscores the importance of good closure reasons in the first place.
4. Sometimes you'll find really old questions that are no longer in compliance with the modern rules, but don't need to be open or deleted. For those you can ask for a [historical lock](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/126587/what-is-a-historical-lock-and-what-is-it-used-for). It's not clear if this question needs one or not. A moderator will have to make that call. You can raise a custom flag if you think a question needs one.

In general, use your best judgment on reopens. If you feel a question was closed incorrectly, then reopen it. That's what it's for. None of the "mortal" SO moderation is of the permanent variety for that reason.

Comment: I checked [question in question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/450027/839601) - 200K views, 36 linked questions. Not a 100% clear cut case for historical lock but still fairly strong one

Comment: @gnat I had asked a mod in chat about it and they weren't sure either.